# How to improve the launch of gitlab-runner?

Tags: gitlab-ci-runner

I installed on my vps gitlab runner, but every time I use in gitlab-ci.yml

```
tags:
 - vps
```

I have a hold of 5 minutes (minimum) each time.

I installed gitlab runner with

```
apt-get install gitlab-runner
```

whereas if I use the gitlab-=runner from gitlab.com I don't get the hold

[image]

gitlab-runner info:

```
gitlab-runner status Runtime platform arch=amd64 os=linux pid=662441 revision=133d7e76 version=15.6.1


concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0
shutdown_timeout = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
```

runner 1:

```
[[runners]]
  name = "name1"
  url = "https://gitlab.com/"
  id = 123
  token = "ABC"
  token_obtained_at = 2022-11-26T20:24:16Z
  token_expires_at = 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z
  executor = "shell"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    MaxUploadedArchiveSize = 0
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
    [runners.cache.azure]
```

runner2:

```
[[runners]]
  name = "runner2"
  url = "https://gitlab.com/"
  id = 456
  token = "ABC"
  token_obtained_at = 2022-11-26T20:34:45Z
  token_expires_at = 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    MaxUploadedArchiveSize = 0
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
    [runners.cache.azure]
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "ruby:latest"
    privileged = false
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
```

thank you

Comment: there is no where near enough info for us to help you here. what does your job log show? what type of runner is it? shell? docker? does the job start imedialy but take a long time to run? does the job sit in pending for some time before moving to the running state then complete quick? what does your gitlab-runner logs show

Comment: It is the time between the push and the launch that takes 4-6 minutes, otherwise the runner works quickly. The log tells me: This task has not yet started

This task is waiting to be chosen by an executor

Comment: I tried to configure the runner inshell, docker, ruby... It's always the same result

Comment: Can you update your question to include in the question your gitlab runner config, Please remember to mask sensitive information like the `token`

Comment: curious if you have changed the `check_interval` in the runner config to something like `300` https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#how-check_interval-works

Comment: Do you have any value set for `check_interval` it will be global config so set in the config.toml but outside of the runners config

Comment: the value of check_interval at the top of the config.toml file is 0

Comment: strange, that should then default to use the value of  `3` maybe restart the runner with logs in `INFO` or `DEBUG` mode and see if that gives you any more info. It sounds like the job is queued but the runner is not polling often or polling slowly

Comment: I deleted gitlab-runner, when I did an impossible stop from start error 5, I uninstall and redo a clean thing

Comment: sudo gitlab-runner start
Runtime platform                                    arch=amd64 os=linux pid=669895 revision=133d7e76 version=15.6.1
FATAL: Failed to start gitlab-runner: exit status 5

Comment: You made me understand that I had a problem with my installation, I deleted everything (and again I had trouble) and the push and direct it started... thank you very much!! :)